# Increase Row Count of ListView with CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'm using a ListView that is populated by a custom CursorAdapter that returns two different Views based on the value of the data in the Cursor for that particular row.

**One View type** contains a TextView, call it TextView1.
**The second View** contains TextView1 and TextView2.

The problem is I'd like the second View to be treated as two rows in the ListView. So Text1 would become a row and Text2 would become another row.

Obviously with Layouts I can make it look like it's a different row, but it's not actually a different row. I can't independently select them, so when I hook into the ListView's OnListItemClick event, I get a single event for clicking TextView1 and TextView2, they are not distinct. Is there a way I can tell the ListView that there are two rows here and not one or is there a way to fake it?

Comment: With `CursorAdapter` one cursor entry is one row, no other way to do it, I suppose. You can always write a custom extension of `ArrayAdapter` or even `BaseAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can tell the ListView that there are two rows here
>   and not one or is there a way to fake it?

You can approach this in two ways. First you could make your own custom `Adapter` that breaks the `Cursor` in the correct number of rows and then simple use one `TextView` per row with `OnItemClickListener`. Depending on the size of the `Cursor`'s data, this could be easy or something to avoid.

The second approach would be to use your current  custom `CursorAdapter` and implement two types of rows(implement the `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` methods), one with a simple `TextView` and a row with two `TextViews`. The trick would be that you can't use the `OnItemClickListener` on the `ListView`, instead you would set your on `OnCLickListeners` on the `TextViews` from the rows. If you make the `TextViews` to occupy the entire row's width and height the effect would be of a row being selected. In the `OnClickListener` for those `TextViews` you could pass the current position of the `Cursor` or the `id` for that row to do whatever you want.